# Taking a reference to an object with a private copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a class T which uses Boost for threading and hence has members with private copy constructors.

I'd would like to pass T by reference to another class.  However, when I try to do so, no matter how I try to do it, I can't get it right.  I can do this by passing a pointer, but not a reference.

**What is the proper way to pass a reference to an object that can't be copied?**

OR: If the answer is "You can't do that by ref, only pointer".  Can you please explain why that is so? Aren't refs merely pointers with gentler syntax?  (I'd like to know both why this distinction was made in the design, and, if at the compilation level, there really is any difference between pointer and references.)

---

**UPDATE**: Before dismissing this, please note:

1. I am getting this from a class using Boost threads, where, pass by reference gave me private copy constructor errors deep within the class, but pass by pointer didn't
2. My understanding is that it is 100% possible to make it possible to stop pass by reference
3. and that Boost threads makes use of it

If my assumptions are wrong, I will accept as correct answer any answer which clarifies where my mistake is.

Comment: The proper way is to pass pass a reference to an object that can't be copied. And don't use the reference to make a copy of the object that can't be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you pass a reference:

```
void foo(int& x)
{}

int main()
{
   int y = 42;
   foo(y);
}
```

Doesn't matter whether the underlying type is copyable or not, because you're not copying it.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper, the problem wasn't the pass-by-reference, but rather that the initializer list did:

```
 ... : mx(x) {};
```

I had thought that if `x` was passed by reference, then `mx(x)` would be a reference to x.  But it's not, it's a copy.

I believe that the fix would have been to declare `mx` as a reference: `int& mx`.

Comment: That's not even valid initializer list syntax... Otherwise you're right though.

Comment: It's not an initializer list, it's a snippet from the ctor

Comment: Yes, it's the member initializer list and, as I said, it is syntactically invalid. Drop the `int`.